# how to get non topmost qgraphicsitem from the scene

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, user-controls

Excuse me if so topic is also created. I have look for it and, regardless, not found one.
Can I get qgraphicsitem by click coordinates that is just beneath the topmost item by cute small way? I mean I can try to use this fact that scene sends click-signal to all items beneath the  cursor position, but it seems like unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QGraphicsView::items(const QPoint& pos) const` to return all the items under a viewport coordinate, they are in descending stacking order ([docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#items-2)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for adequate answer! Seems like my eyes was tired that i didn't find it by myself.